# Change background color of transform:rotate object on hover in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, css

I'm having a weird CSS problem in firefox.  If I have a rotated object, position it to "fixed", I can't make the background change on hover.

If I remove the rotation, or remove the fixed position (such as change to absolute), then the hover works.  But I need the rotation and the fixed position.  Anyone got any ideas why this happens?

See example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.testing {
    background:#00F;
    color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:300px;
    left:400px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);

  -webkit-transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  -o-transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}
.testing:hover {
    background:#F00;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" class="testing">Testing Background Color</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where did you use the A class in your html ?

Comment: It is working fine in Firefox 9.

Comment: Note: I'm using Firefox 17.0.1

Comment: You can try defining a named class in CSS and using it in the element

Comment: I've set the test link to a separate class name to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think you've found a bug in FireFox. This code works fine in JSFiddle, but not as a file on its own. Also, it seems that if your hover declaration changes the shape of the block, it'll work. But if you just change the colours, it doesn't. Also, if you change the sizes such that the result has the same size (eg: reduce the width by 1, but add a 1px border), it still will not work.

Comment: Thanks Gareth, your size change work around has solved by problem, because I've doing a fixed position with left:0px; So I can just increase the width 1px and left -1px

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

this was my code

```
<div id='lightbox'>
            <div id='addtocart'>
                <a href='$link'></a>
            </div>
         </div>
```

the lightbox is having the  position:fixed
and the add to cart is having the button

in this example its not working

when i'm doing this

```
<div id='lightbox'></div>
        <div id='addtocart'>
            <a href='$link'></a>
        </div>
```

its working again

```
     #lightbox{
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            z-index:12;
            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            overflow:hidden;
}


     #addtocart a:link{
            position:fixed;
            bottom:10%;
            right:10%;
            background: url("/vans/afbeeldingen/Navigatie/cart2.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0px transparent;
            width:199px;
            height:49px; 
}


     #addtocart a:hover{
            background: url("/vans/afbeeldingen/Navigatie/cart.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0px transparent;    
}
```

so when your having a button in a fixed div its not showing a hover any more.

*the first code is only not working in firefox*